# Unable to resolve "../../App" from "node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

When I try running my expo (version 4.0.16) app on a mobile device, I get `Unable to resolve "../../App" from "node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js"`

I tried: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/vue-native-core/issues/117, and [Unable to resolve "../../App" from "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198283/unable-to-resolve-app-from-node-modules-expo-appentry-js).

However the github one did not work.(`"packagerOpts": { "sourceExts": [ "js", "json", "ts", "tsx", "jsx", "vue"], "config": "metro.config.js"`} didn't do anything) My main file is called app.js.

I tried following the stackoverflow post

```
I ran into this problem too. I used the expo cli to make the project which sets up your app.json file 
with "entryPoint": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js". AppEntry.js tries to default import from a js file 
called App in the root directory. Make sure you have a file called App.js|.tsx that default exports a 
react component.
```

and now my app.js looks like

```
class App extends React.Component  {
//stuff
}
export default App;
```

but that also didn't change anything, and I don't know if I understood what I was supposed to do exactly. Anyways, if anyone has any ideas, please let me know.